# Concurrency in SoundPool and MediaPlayer?

Tags: java, android, media-player, audio, soundpool

I dunno if my sounds are just too quiet but right now I am programming a Rhythm game for Android and when you open it on the menuActivity (where you can press "Play" "Options" "About" and "Exit), it will select a random song (if any exist) and play it, get the BPM from a file (which contains all the "tapObjects") and will pulse the logo.

So in this menuActivity, I have a public static MediaPlayer called mPlayer that handles ALL background music for all activities, if the song need be changed then it will reset() and then reload how one normally would.

My question is, does SoundPool sound effects (which I have about 7, all are less than 2 seconds) layer ontop of the BGM from MediaPlayer?

Say I have a song called abc.mp3 playing in the background and it's 60 seconds in, and the player gets a "multiplier up", and that triggers SOUNDLEVELUP from SoundPool, will they play concurrently or do I need a different implementation for this to work?

Regards,
Annie

Answer (score 0):

Is your question just *Can I play a SoundPool sound concurrently with a MediaPlayer track?*

If that's the case than yes you can, you should have no problems using them at the same time.

Comment: Yes I meant that but for some reason my sound isn't playing

Comment: Have you looked at the output logcat to see if something there is the problem?